# How to keep the original css file after including bootstrap link?

Tags: html, css

I include bootstrap link in my website like this:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And right below, I include my own css stylesheet like this:

```
<link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But as I included bootstrap, I could no longer edit the website's style through my original stylesheet in `header.css`. I can still edit the website's appearance through `<style="....">`, but I'd like to integrate every style in the css file. Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: you should check what cascade actually means in css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem on [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1):

CSS stands for [Cascading Style Sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), which may sound a bit arbitrary, but it's very important to understand that it functions exactly as the name states. The styles "cascade" down the file. You can easily override any attribute you want if you put it further down the file. If you don't want it overwritten, you give it more weight, or more accurately, more [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Many bootstrap styles are notoriously specific, and require heavier selectors to overwrite.

So first of all, make sure you're loading you `header.css` file _after your `bootstrap.min.css`, and make sure you're using specific enough selectors.

Take a look at this snippet: If you want the `.alt` div to be black, you'll need to make sure you're using a heavier selector if your library is using a really specific one, even if your selector comes afterwards.

```css
/* Library.css */
div {
  background: #0095ee;
  color: #fff;
}

div + div.alt {
  background: #ee3d96;
}

/* Custom.css */
.alt {
  background: #000
}
```

```html
<div>I'm the first div</div>
<div class="alt">I'm the second div</div>
<div>I'm the third div</div>
```